# Sharepoint Script Editor Web Part Not Showing Up

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, spfx, sharepoint-2019, spfx-extension

I have SP 2019 setup and I cloned and generated the .sppkg file from the solution below:

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor-onprem

I uploaded to the apps store of the site collection and chose to deploy to all sites. Now, on my Sharepoint Communication Site, when I try to add the web part, it does not show up in the drop-down. Is there any change I need to perform? I am new to Sharepoint development.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2019 does not have really the option to deploy to all sites. You can select it but it does not deploy it to all sites. You need to add app to the site manually or by script (powershell, ...). Go to site contents, add an app, add that app to site, wait for adding and then you can add it in the drop down in your site.